# Spotify Apps - 'Add as Playlist' button for playlist created within app

Tags: spotify

My code loops through a number of albums to get their tracks and adds them to a playlist variable

```
playlist.add(m.Track.fromURI(results.tracks[j].uri));
```

Which i previously set up with

```
var playlist = new m.Playlist('robs top 5');
```

How can i now create a 'Add as Playlist' button which will turn this playlist object into a playlist for the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a button and then call for

```
playlist.subscribed = true;
```

But I don't think this works for self generated playlists, But let me know.

-edit
K, Ive sorted things out for you. What you wanna do when you want a subsribe button is to give your playlist a name and then all you need to add is that subscribed is true.

```
$('#subscribe').on('click', function() {
    var playlist = new models.Playlist('Playlist Name');
            playlist.subscribed = true;
            $.each(tracks, function(index, track){
                playlist.add(track);
            });
    });
```

This is a little piece of how i did it.

Comment: I think this part only work for playlist already existing, but for a created playlist, it should not work

Comment: IF this doesn't work for playlists that dont exist is there a way to create the playlist first and get a URL? I see that other apps manage to create playlists on the fly from recommendations.

Comment: @GeraudPuechaldou I have used this for my own dynamically created playlist. I have no experience with existing playlists fromURI..

Comment: @RobDove If you want my source code you can just PM me, you could take a look at how I have done things

Comment: @Basje, because me without subscribe it's also working. I used subscribe for existing playlist and didn't for dynamic... It should be something from API.

Comment: @GeraudPuechaldou Oh, you are right it also works without x.subscribed = true ..strange

Answer (score 0):

Here, how I did :

```
$('myplaylistbutton').live('click',function(e){
var myAwesomePlaylist = new m.Playlist(album.artist.name + " - " + pl.name);
$.each(pl.data.all(),function(i,track){
    myAwesomePlaylist.add(track);
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a playlist, you'll need to have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Instantiate the global sp object; include models & views */
    var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
    var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
    var views = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/views');

    $("#subscribe").click(function(playlist){
        var playlist = models.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:spotify:playlist:3Yrvm5lBgnhzTYTXx2l55x");
        playlist.subscribed = true;

        playlist.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {
            console.log("Playlist is subscribed!");
        });
     });

});
```